# Can i place a javascript comment in the middle of a property?

Tags: javascript, cookies, comments, document

I would like to add a comment block (/**/) in the middle of a javascript code for obfuscation reasonds.

I want this:
    alert(document.cookie);

to look like this:
    alert(document.co/**/okie);

but adding the comment block makes the code invalid. Why? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Think of a comment block as a space: If a space breaks the code, then so will the comment. For example, this would be fine: `alert(/* comment */document./* comment */cookie/* comment */);` If you're trying to obfuscate JavaScript, comments are not the way to go (a simple JSLint will remove all comments anyways). The question should be: What methods are effective in JavaScript obfuscation, and in that case, your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397). If you're trying to hide the cookies, don't even try, a simple F12 -> Resources -> Cookies shows.

Comment: @DaveChen You should post this as an answer mate.

Comment: @Troy No need, you already have! +1

Comment: @daveChen, your comment was so complete and it still all fit inside a comment block. Awesome!

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks that was very useful! I will try your obfuscation methods too. You couldve added your comment as an answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it won't be cookie anymore dear. It's like adding a space in the middle of the property, therefore making it co okie. But it's fine if you do:

```
alert(/* Comment here */ document.cookie /* Or here */);
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that you can have spaces between objects and their properties (just not spaces within the identifiers as you pointed out). `alert   (   document   .   cookie   )   ;`